# Bash to check cloud foundry logs

Tags: bash, null, cloud-foundry, tail

I have a CF application and running cf logs -appname- will essentially tail the logs and write the output to terminal...

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html#tail-log

whats an ideal way for bash to check activity in this "real-time stream" of data?

Comment: What is the result of 'checking activity'?

Comment: Check for any actual log lines of output… If not triggers an action

Comment: You want to check something like 'every 5 minutes there is at least 3 lines of output'? This should be stated in the question more clearly.

Comment: Like I run the command and within 5min there should be some lines of output

Comment: This could help you a little https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324213/pass-through-pipe-with-timeout, but the solutions are mostly ugly. The thread reading from the pipe will be blocked in the `read()`, so you need a separate watchdog thread/process. And take care to get rid of buffering (eg by using stderr).

Answer (score 0):

This is may be good enough for what you are doing:

```
touch oldfile
echo 10 > sleeptime
while :
do
  cf log application --recent > file
  if
    diff -q file oldfile   >&/dev/null
  then
    # take some action on file
    mv file oldfile
  fi

  sleep $(cat sleeptime)
done
```

I'm suggesting that instead of tailing the log, just use cf's --recent parameter to let them do the work for you.  I assume that it will return the same output if the logs haven't changed.

Comment: I suppose I should comment on the sleep $(cat sleeptime) construct.  You may find it useful to have a file (in this case sleeptime) that you can modify to change the period that you check the logs.  This allows you to change the behavior while the script is running.

Comment: Check out firehose plugin `https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/firehose-plugin`